# Why querying process available CPUs return all CPUs?

Tags: c, unix, process, cpu, affinity

I'm trying to query the process available CPUs (on which CPUs he can run) using cpuset_getaffinity.

```
cpuset_getaffinity(CPU_LEVEL_WHICH, CPU_WHICH_PID, getpid(),
                             sizeof(*cpuset), cpuset);
```

The cpu set returned by the query has all the system CPUs.
I was wondering why and in which cases not all CPUs are available for a process?

Comment: Generally, a process can be run on any general CPU in a given system. The default cpuset mask is all ones for the CPUs in the system (e.g. on a 4 cpu system, the mask is 0x0F). To restrict, one uses `cpuset_setaffinity` with some of the bits cleared.

Comment: So if I want my process to run on some specific group of CPUs because they are connected to some underlined peripheral I should cpuset_setaffinity?
For example limit it to group of CPUs that are part of the same socket.
Can it do more harm than good?

Answer (score 1):

You can define witch CPUs are dedicated for lets say some processes you wanna highlight. I use 2 out of 8 CPUs for DPKD.

> [root@myserver]  cat /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 isolcpus=2,3 default_hugepagesz=2M hugepagesz=2M hugepages=1024"

You see that isolcpus=2,3 are dedicated for DPKD and they are 100% used.

%Cpu0  :  0.7 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.7 id,
%Cpu1  : 12.5 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.9 id,

%Cpu2  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,
%Cpu3  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,

%Cpu4  :  1.3 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.6 id,
%Cpu5  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,
%Cpu6  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,
%Cpu7  :  0.3 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.7 id,

So in this case, if this was your question, you see that not all CPUs are available to handle incoming processes.